# Debug Guage-python code in VSC: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, getgauge

I'm new to the Gauge test framework and trying to get the debugging to work with my Python/Visual Studio Code setup.

When I try to debug a spec/scenario  within the IDE (using the Gauge plugin) I get the following error message:

Running tool:

> gauge run c:\test\gauge\specs\login-logout.spec:5 --simple-console
>   --hide-suggestion

Error Message:

> Connection closed [127.0.0.1:54738] cause: read tcp
>   127.0.0.1:54734->127.0.0.1:54738: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.   Stacktrace: 
>        Error Message: write tcp 127.0.0.1:54734->127.0.0.1:54738: use of closed network connection   Stacktrace:

Any help or hints how to solve this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect this is because the gauge-python runner is getting killed for some reason. You could check the logs. But if you need help, I think we should [chat](https://gitter.im/getgauge/gauge)

Comment: When I downloaded the latest nightly build of the Gauge plugin it started to work!